# How to count number of user chat with another user

Tags: mysql

I try few mysql statement but didn't come to my expectations.

[image]

How to get the total of to_user chat and order by the lowest total?

Let say in this case,

id 7 chat with 2 user

id 6 chat with only 1 user.

so the minimum will be id 6.

Can someone help me with sql statement?

This is what my expected result

| count | to_user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 6 |

Comment: Can you share the result you're trying to get for this data? I'm not clear on the format you're looking for

Comment: What about to_user=5?

Comment: @Mureinik Can see the post, i mentioned what result i want to get. From to_user column, id 7 actually chat with 2 id from from_user table and id 6 chat with 1 id only. So i want to display the list of it in desc order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem will be solved with the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(from_user)) AS total,to_user
FROM chats
GROUP BY to_user
ORDER BY total ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you index the junction in both directions, otherwise it will BYITA later!

```
ALTER TABLE messages
    ADD INDEX idx_from_to (from_user, to_user),
    ADD INDEX idx_to_from (to_user, from_user);
```

---

You may want to take into account the fact that the full list of chats for a given user is `(from any user, to given user) UNION (to any user, from given user)`.

Consider user 1 in your sample data, who has sent messages to 5, 6, & 7 but not received any. And user 5 has sent to user 7 and received from user 1.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(from_user)) AS count, to_user
FROM messages
GROUP BY to_user
ORDER BY count ASC
```

returns the following (which matches the expected result detailed in your question, errors aside)

| count | to_user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |

whereas

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, from_user AS user
FROM (
    SELECT from_user, to_user FROM messages
    UNION
    SELECT to_user, from_user FROM messages
) t
GROUP BY from_user
ORDER BY count ASC;
```

returns

| count | user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 |